# Get order of a content type's fields

Tags: 7, entities

When I manage fields in content type edition I can put them in order. How could I retrieve this information to use it in a custom module. In Database there is no any column which saves weight order information of fields as they appears in "Manage fields" tab in content type edition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [field_info_instance()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!field.info.inc/function/field_info_instance/7.x)

```
  $entity_type = 'node';
  $field_name = 'body';
  $bundle_name = 'article';
  $body = field_info_instance($entity_type, $field_name, $bundle_name);
```

Which gives you access to numerous config/settings

[image]

```
  $body_weight = $body['display']['default']['weight'];
```